# Rails 3 autocomplete: Whats my route?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm am trying to implement JQuery autocomplete in my Rails 3 app. Here are the relevant code:

## view

```
   <%= event_form.text_field :evaluator_id, :class => "form-control" %>
```

## js.coffee

```
$("#event_evaluator_id").autocomplete
        source: "presenters_path"
```

## route

```
  match "events/presenters/" => "events#presenter_tokens", :as => 'presenters'
```

## events controller

```
  def presenter_tokens
    if(@presenter_tokens.nil?)
      @presenter_tokens = self.presenter_connections.order(:position).pluck(:learner_id).join(',')
    end
    @presenter_tokens
  end
```

The error I am getting in the JS console when I start typing in the text field is:

```
GET http://localhost/events/2119/presenters_path?term=ma 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: In your route you not passing event_id, while your request contains event_id. Fix that in your routes

Comment: @Avdept changed route to `match "events/:id/presenters" => "events#presenter_tokens", :as => 'presenters'` but getting the same error. I actually don't need the event id for anything. I just need to get the results from the presenter_tokens method w/out any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the javascript. Javascript does not have access to the helper methods.

```
$("#event_evaluator_id").autocomplete
    source: "presenters_path"
```

Here you are telling javascript that source is literally "presenters_path", thats what you see in the console as being appended to the path. Change the source to actual path `/events/presenters/` and it should get to the correct route.